# How to check existence of a property in Outlook Interop?

Tags: com-interop, office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

I am trying to determine sender of a email in Outlook 2007 and above. In Outlook 2010 you have a `Sender` property on the `MailItem` object while in Outlook 2007 you have to do it differently like mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655104/outlook-2007-vsto-add-in-get-email-sender-address).

So now I need to know whether current version of Outlook supports the `Sender` property, and if it does not, use the other method. The reason for doing this is I would prefer to use the `Sender` property for compatibility with future versions of Outlook rather than having condition on version of Outlook.

So the question is how do I determine whether a property exists in Outlook Interop ? Obviously, this being a COM object I cannot use reflection here.

Comment: you've tried the try..catch-approach? That's often needed in COM interop.

Comment: @Scoregraphic, I had already tried that approach but it does not work. Outlook simply exits silently from in-between without going to the catch block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the MailItem.ItemProperties collection to check for the "Sender" property. Below is the code

```cs
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem myMail;

//Code to get the mail
....

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemProperties mailProps = myMail.ItemProperties;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemProperty mailProp = mailProps.Item  ("Sender"); //the parameter is case-sensitive

if(mailProp != null)
{
    //get email address using Sender object
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry theSender = myMail.Sender;
}
else
{
    //use alternate method for Outlook 2007 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to see if the property exists

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit? I don't know how I should use this (and it doesn't seem like any registered user so far did)