# Is it possible to get owner of a shared calendar [Outlook Interop]

Tags: c#, outlook, interop

I want to find the owner of an appointment I'm creating on a shared calender. Is that possible?

I'm having the storeId from the folder by doing:

```
Folder folder = Appointment.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder as Folder;
string storeid = folder.StoreID;
```

How can I get the owner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem as easy as it sounds. I thought there was an `Owner` property, but there isn't unfortunately.

I found this [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mstehle/archive/2006/09/07/howto-determining-the-owner-of-a-shared-folder.aspx) that explains how you can extract the owner from the `StoreID` you already have.

The most important thing is to convert the `string` from a hexadecimal representation, and then use this regex:

```
private string ParseEntryID(string storeID)
{
    string s = HexReader.GetString(storeID);
    //TODO: These values might be different depending on
    what you have named your groups in ESM
    const string REG_EX = @"/o=First Organization/ou=First
        Administrative Group/cn=Recipients/cn=(\w+)";
    Match m = Regex.Match(s, REG_EX);

    return m.Value;
}
```

The code for the `HexReader` can be found in the article.

Comment: Thanks. The owner is not at that point of the string. Instead it is in front of /o=First Organization (maybe change between outlook 2010 / 2013). But the method helped me. So now I only must use a regex to get the mailadress.

Comment: @SteffenSchindler: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655104/outlook-2007-vsto-add-in-get-email-sender-address).

Comment: Doesn't work because in this example there is an email and it will get the sender. In my example I have an appointment and don't want the organizer. Instead i want the owner of the calender. So if you're a participant than the owner ist the participant of the meeting.